# How to add a function to the Qt Mainloop

Tags: python, qt

Is there an easy way in Qt to add a function to the standard Qt mainloop (`exec()`)? Ideally something like how it would be done in GTK:

```
import gobject
gobject.timeout_add(milliseconds, callback)
```

I need this for a simple GUI which just grabs and displays a video feed from a camera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `QTimer`:

```
timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(callback)
timer.start(msecs)
```

For single-shot timeouts, you can use the `singleShot` class method directly:

```
QTimer.singleShot(msecs, callback);
```